# How to differentiate a jstree drop as child or sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using the jstree drag and drop plugin.

When dropping one can drop as a child or drop as a sibling.
The difference is the arrow which is shown before drop.

This right arrow is shown beside the target node or above the target node.

**Is there a way to identify if the right arrow is beside or above the target node?**

I can capture the target node by using the hover_node event, but I do not know if the drop is as child or as sibling.

UPDATE:
I noticed that two new html tags are inserted when a drap and drop operation is happening - "vakata-dnd" and "jstree-marker". The top difference between the two elements seems to partly determine whether the dragged item will later be a child or sibling. However the hover_node is only fired once when the row containing a node is hovered on. Is there a way to catch every movement of the mouse?

Answer (score 2):

Use JSTree's check_callback function. It passes these arguments
`operation, node, parent, position, more` which can be used to get the information you need. `position` returns a number, 0 for hover which will produce a child if dropped and a 1 for sibling. Here are links with more documentation:

http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=check_call&f=$.jstree.defaults.core.check_callback
https://github.com/vakata/jstree#more-on-configuration

```
 $("#tree").jstree({
  "core" : {
    "check_callback" : function (operation, node, parent, position, more) {
      if(operation === "copy_node" || operation === "move_node") {
        if(parent.id === "#") {
          return false; // prevent moving a child above or below the root
        }
      },
      return true; // allow everything else
    }
  },
  "plugins" : ["dnd","contextmenu"]
});
```

To understand the output better pass the arguments to the console:

```
$("#tree").jstree({
  "core" : {
    "check_callback" : function (operation, node, parent, position, more) {
      console.log(operation, node, parent, position, more);
      },
      return true;
    }
  },
  "plugins" : ["dnd"]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else still looking, it might help to refer to this SO post.

[JsTree v3.0 drag and drop plugin. Reference target node upon dropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892906/jstree-v3-0-drag-and-drop-plugin-reference-target-node-upon-dropping)

Also, since you were asking how to check every movement of the mouse, see [check_while_dragging](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.dnd.check_while_dragging) which allows the `dnd_move` event to fire every time the mouse position of the drag changes.