# JSTree Drag n Drop Checking Callback

Tags: jstree

I'm using [JSTree](https://www.jstree.com/) and it has shown to be an awesome tool. 
Using the Drag and Drop plugin I came across this:

When I drag a file to a folder with valid_children that does not allow files it does not show the red cross, but also does not allow to drop (as valid_children expected behavior). For a better user expecience I need to show the cross when the parent node's valid_children does not contain the node being dragged's type. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

[image: Example of what I am looking for.]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution and it differs a little from [what I've found in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892906/jstree-v3-0-drag-and-drop-plugin-reference-target-node-upon-dropping)

- explicitly define your valid_childrens on "types" configuraton.
- add parameters on check_callback to function(operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more)
- add to check_callback:

`switch (operation) {
                        case 'move_node':
                            return ($.inArray(node.type, this.get_rules(more.ref).valid_children) != -1);
                        default:
                            return true;
                    }`